# VHDL Write only 16 bits into a 32 bit register location

Tags: vhdl

I am currently working on making a modified 32-bit MIPS CPU in VHDL. I have a 32 bit wide register bank with 16 locations which is written to using this piece of code: `register_content(to_integer(unsigned(write_address(3 downto 0)))) <= ALU_Result;` Where register_content is the array and write address is the location in the register bank where the 32-bit result from an ALU is being written to. Here is how I have created the register bank.

[image]

Don't worry about what is in the register bank at the moment they are just some values that I am using for testing. Now the register works fine and the ALU_Result gets written where it is supposed to.

The problem that I have is that I have to implement a load immediate instruction which is specified below:

[image]

The 0x0f is just the opcode which isn't relevent for this question. The main bit is the description where it states that I have to store a 16-bit immediate value into the lower 16 bits of register rt.

I tried to implement this by using the same line of code as I have used previously but try to specify the lower 16 bits `register_content(15 downto 0)(to_integer(unsigned(read_address_2(3 downto 0)))) <= instruction_17_2;` (instruction_17_2 is the immediate value and read_address_2 is rt) but I am getting an error upon simulation that states "expression has 16 elements ; expected 32".

So obviously the way that I have tried to implement it didn't work. Does anyone know how to only write the lower 16 bits to a 32 bit location? Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would show declarations it as well as a MIPS green card it sounds like it should be something like `register_content(to_integer(unsigned(read_address_2(3 downto 0))(15 downto 0) <= instruction_17_2;` Where you slice the indexed array element as the target.  In addition to an MCVe the complete error message would be helpful.

Comment: The Xilinx XST ERROR:HDLCompiler:410 reflects IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update "For a composite signal R, an implicit subtype conversion is performed to the subtype of R; for each element of R, there shall be a matching element in both the driving and the effective value, and vice versa." The solutions comes from 8.5 Slice names "A slice name denotes a one-dimensional array composed of a sequence of consecutive elements of another one-dimensional array." Please make your question an [MCVe](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so an answer doesn't simply reflect an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user1155120, the answer was simply me not having the `(15 downto 0)` portion of the code in the correct position.

This is how it should look like:

`register_content(to_integer(unsigned(read_address_2(3 downto 0))(15 downto 0) <= instruction_17_2;`